# React Native AsyncStorage ')' to end a compound expression

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, asyncstorage

I am getting this error in my react-native app.

**Unexpected JS Expection: Unexpected identifier '_asyncStorage'. Expected ')' to end a compound expression.**

This couold be simply a syntax problem but I could not figure it out.

I am fairly new to the framework and trying to implement Redux for user login and registration functions. As I cannot use `localStorage`, I am using `AsyncStorage` but I am not really familiar if I can simply somehow replace my localstorage functions with `AsyncStorage`. I already completed the web app version of the same app. I think there is something wrong with my store.js file for Redux. Here it is if you can help with the error

````
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { userLoginReducer, userRegisterReducer } from './src/redux/reducers/userReducers';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    //contains reducers
    userLogin: userLoginReducer,
    userRegister: userRegisterReducer
});

// const UnparsedUserInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userInfo");
// const ParsedUserInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userInfo");

const userInfoFromStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userInfo") ? await AsyncStorage.getItem("userInfo") : null;

const initialState = {
    userLogin: {userInfo: userInfoFromStorage}
};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware)
);

export default store```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to await outside of an async scope. You can't await like that. You need to have an async function to handle your promises and save your returned data in a state then you can use this state in your expressions, such

```
    const [userInfoState, setUserInfoState] = useState(null);

    const getUserInfoAsync = async () => {
          const userInfo = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userInfo');
          setUserInfoState(userInfo);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      getUserInfoAsync();
    }, []);

    const initialState = {
      userLogin: {userInfo: userInfoState}
    };
```

Comment: Sorry, can you expand on what you mean? I am a newbie on this and have been trying to do it but I might have understood your comment in a wrong way

Comment: Yeah sure, so you need an async function. Let me update my answer.